# Detect direct pushes to master w/GitHub Actions

Tags: github, slack, github-actions

We currently have a GitHub repository where our `master` branch is protected for everyone except admins, who are able to commit and push directly to the branch without first opening a pull request. We're looking to find a way to send a Slack notification anytime an admin commits directly to `master` in order to call attention to the fact that there was an override of the branch protections. This may happen intentionally due to extreme circumstances or, worst case, by mistake (which will need to be addressed).

This seems like it'd be possible with a combination of the [GitHub Slack action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/slack-notify), the [`if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps) key on the job/step definition, and ideally some piece of information from the [`push`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#push) event JSON.

The last part is where I'm stuck: **I don't see an obvious way to use the data contained in the `push` event to differentiate between one-off commits that would violate our branch protection policy and a normal/compliant pull request**.

Does anyone have any ideas as to whether or not this is possible? Perhaps there's another event that I should be attaching this workflow to that would give me the information I'd need to tell the difference and launch the Slack notification?

Comment: you can use this request to see if the commit has any pull request associated: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-pull-requests-associated-with-a-commit, you can also check who is the author of the commit, I think this is enough information to differentiate the commits, what do you think?

Comment: @soltex I think you can post this as an answer. Cross-referencing the commits of the push with commits of any merged PR seem to be the only way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, using GitHub Actions to do this kind of notification is problematic because the user can simply remove or neutralize the code that reports this and then push to the main branch.  The Actions workflow that's used will be the one pushed into the repo as part of that commit, so this won't be an effective control.

You'd want to probably instead use a webhook to notify a service of this fact and then look at the `HEAD` commit, parse the commit message to extract the PR number, and verify that the second parent of the commit is the same as the head of the PR.  Note that this won't work if you're using squash merges, because there's no easy way to verify that the commit created by a squash merge is the same as the one created by the branch from which it was created.

Comment: I think this + @soltex's suggestion is a good solution to the problem I asked.  We actually managed to satisfy our requirements by simplifying things and just logging all pushes to `master` into Slack, which notifies us both of PRs coming in and direct commits.